# Lost 25k XP on Agar.io and I do not know why

Tags: agar.io

I was playing Agar.io earlier today for about 2 hours in one life. I ended up getting around 25k XP as a result after dying. I came back to Agar.io a minute ago and I watched my XP bar go down to what it previously was. Why did it do this? Does it think I am cheating?

Answer (score 1):

Agar.io is a constantly changing game. The experience system is still new, and as such, still has bugs.

Deleting a players experience appears to be random, though there are reports that if you refresh the browser a few times, it will "remember".

Comment: I don't think it "forgot" my XP because when I opened it it said 34513 XP and the bar when down to 9513 before my eyes. Thanks for the response  though. Refreshing doesn't seem to help unfortunately. :(

Comment: Regardless, this is exactly what happens with this bug. It happened to me, too. Take it with a grain of salt. As it is, there does not appear to be any real advantage to the experience system (you start off bigger, but only 10 seconds worth of gaming bigger)

Comment: @Timelord64 I wonder how long you would have to play to gain enough xp to make your starting condition feasibly useful. As is, I start around size 40 now. Which to me makes start up a lot easier than starting at 10. But then even if I started at 1000 it would only be 10 seconds worth of gaming bigger in a game like agar :)